# What are the system requirements for a squid forward proxy?

Tags: proxy, squid

I would like to set up a squid forward proxy to proxy data outbound data from hosts that have no internet access.

The flow would be from application hosts located in a secure zone with no internet access, through a firewall, to the proxy instance in a less secure zone, and then finally out to the internet through the proxy's gateway. The vast majority of traffic through the proxy will be outbound (I'd put the ratio at >99% egress to <1% ingress - uploading telemetry data to vendors).

We've tested this and it seems to work just fine, the problem is I don't know how to dimension the squid proxies.

The problem I am encountering is that all [squid system requirements](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidMemory) seem to be expecting that you are using squid as a cache (relationship of the amount of ram to the amount of storage). We aren't.

Per the squid documentation:

> As a rule of thumb on Squid uses approximately 10 MB of RAM per GB of
> the total of all cache_dirs (more on 64 bit servers such as Alpha),
> plus your cache_mem setting and about an additional 10-20MB. It is
> recommended to have at least twice this amount of physical RAM
> available on your Squid server. For a more detailed discussion on
> Squid's memory usage see the sections above.

If I am not caching data, I have no cache dirs, so the calculation cache_dirs in GB (0gb) * 10MB RAM would be 0MB RAM, plus the additional 10+20 would only be about 20-40MB of RAM. That makes no sense, obviously - a server needs RAM, and I don't even think the base OS would run in that footprint.

Is there some other means of calculating the minimum requirements of Squid?

Comment: There is no way around *testing* this. The memory footprint squid adds onto the underlying systems requirements can indeed be negligible - for small amounts of concurrent requests.